# jquery form validation

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, radio-button

I have a page with two tables. The first is visible and the second is hidden when the page loads.

If the last two items (in color) in the first table have either "Yes" choice selected, then the second table appears.

I need to add validation to make sure all visible items are selected before the form submits. The problem I'm having is that if the second table is hidden (because "No" is selected for items 8 and 9), the form should submit the data from the first table because the second table is not showing. However, if both tables are showing, then all responses are required before the form submits.

http://jsfiddle.net/mrfisherman2010/dvzsf/2/

I would appreciate help on this. I've really been struggling.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the [jQuery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/). It lets you have arbitrary validation rules and dependencies.

```
  "my_field": {
    required: {
      depends: function(element) {
        var result =...some javascript code...;
        return result;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I tried to implement the jQuery validation plugin. Here's my attempt: http://mrwishywashywindowcleaning.com/QUESTION.html . It's almost working but when the second table is hidden (because "No" is selected for items 8 and 9), the form still requires the items in the hidden table to be completed.

Comment: Updated with a dependency example. Does that help?

Comment: Why dont try to add a if statement to check if the table visibility is on or off... and then run the validation depending on that state?

Comment: I'm not sure how to add that statement to my code. Could you add it here, http://jsfiddle.net/mrfisherman2010/dvzsf/2/ and save a new version so I can see what you mean? Thanks

Comment: It would go in the rules section (which you have in mrwishywashywindowcleaning.com/QUESTION.html). I'm not sure what the condition is, so I can't write the code.